# Some xgboost options do not differentiate predictions

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I want to customize my model with a few parameters and choose the best one. I want to customize the `objective` property, `eval_metric` and possibly `feval`. My problem is that the properties `eval_metric` and `feval` do not affect the prediction at all. I tried to specify the `disable_default_eval_metric:1` property but it didn't help.
What is the reason?

```
y1 = xgb.train({'objective': 'reg:squaredlogerror'},dtrain=dtrain).predict(dtest)
y2 = xgb.train(
    {'objective': 'reg:squaredlogerror', 'disable_default_eval_metric':1, 'eval_metric':'rmsle'},
    dtrain = dtrain
).predict(dtest)
```

Prediction:

```
y1 = [3.9530325, 4.1704693, 4.18354, 4.1704693, 3.9317188]
y2 = [3.9530325, 4.1704693, 4.18354, 4.1704693, 3.9317188]
```

Answer (score 1):

As the name implies, `eval_metric` is only used for *evaluation*, and it does not affect in any way the model training; it only reports back the value of the chosen metric(s). During training, the model only tries to optimize the `objective`, and it does not bother at all with any `eval_metric` (save for reporting it back, and possibly using it for early stopping, if such an option has been selected).

This is the reason why you can use multiple functions in `eval_metric`; from the [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#learning-task-parameters):

> User can add multiple evaluation metrics.

This would *not* be the case if `eval_metric` was directly used for model optimization during training, as it would raise the issue of *which single one* to optimize. Notice that, in contrast to `eval_metric`, you cannot have multiple objective functions.

Given that, what you report is absolutely expected, i.e. your models are actually the same in both cases.